# How to edit a field in a TreeView in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, xmlnode

I have a TreeView:

```
<TreeView Name="OOB"
```

And I know the item that was clicked on:

```
 selectedNode = (XmlNode)OOB.SelectedItem;
```

The TreeView is built from this XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Army>
    <ArmyName>The Army of Northern Virginia</ArmyName>
     <Commander> 
         <CommanderName>The Emperor Napoleon</CommanderName>
         <CommanderLeadership>94</CommanderLeadership> 
            <Division>
                <DivisionCommanderName>Major General William T. Sherman</DivisionCommanderName>
                <DivisionCommanderLeadership>78</DivisionCommanderLeadership>
                <Unit>
                    <UnitName>Chasseurs à Cheval Garde</UnitName>
                    <UnitIcon>Cavalry.png</UnitIcon>
                    <UnitType>Cavalry</UnitType>
                    <UnitKStrength>3</UnitKStrength>
                    <UnitStrength>456</UnitStrength>
                    <UnitQuality>94</UnitQuality>
                    <UnitMorale>72</UnitMorale>
                    <UnitLeadership>74</UnitLeadership>
                    <UnitAmmunition>99</UnitAmmunition>
                </Unit>
                <Unit>
                    <UnitName>Battery B 4th US Artillery</UnitName>
                    <UnitIcon>Artillery.png</UnitIcon>
                    <UnitType>Artillery</UnitType>
                    <UnitKStrength>3</UnitKStrength>
                    <UnitStrength>4456</UnitStrength>
                    <UnitQuality>88</UnitQuality>
                    <UnitMorale>65</UnitMorale>
                    <UnitLeadership>82</UnitLeadership>
                    <UnitAmmunition>25</UnitAmmunition>
                </Unit>
            </Division>
            <Division>
                <DivisionCommanderName>Spoons Butler</DivisionCommanderName>
                <DivisionCommanderLeadership>18</DivisionCommanderLeadership>
```

And, after a dialog box pops up and disappears I want to put the new value from the dialog box into the field:

```
<DivisionCommanderLeadership>78</DivisionCommanderLeadership>
```

For example, how do I write BACK a value into a specific TreeView field?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem (actually for another field, but same difference):
MainWindow.SelectedNode.FirstChild.InnerText = CommanderName.Text;